# Complex numer equation

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Determine all complex numbers $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $z^{n-1}$  =  $\bar{z}$ .

I'm not sure if I'm doing this question right, but would the solutions be $+ 1,-1$ or $0$?

Comment: Since, $z = \vert z \vert e^{i\phi}$, we have that $\vert z \vert^{n-1} e^{i(n-1)\phi} = \vert z \vert e^{-i\phi}$. Thus, what you want to solve is $\vert z \vert ^{n-1} = \vert z \vert$ and $(n-1) \phi \mod 2\pi = -\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, partly, yes, these are solutions (unless $n=1$ and $z=0$) but there might be other solutions as well.

Use *polar coordinates*, i.e. assume that $z$ has distance $r$ from $0$ (i.e. $|z|=r$) and it encloses angle $\alpha$ with the right wing of the real axis.
Then $z^{n-1}$ will have length $r^{n-1}$ and angle $(n-1)\alpha$, while $\bar z$ has length $r$ and angle $-\alpha$.

Comment: Could you provide me with all the solutions to see if I'm doing this right?